# MS Graph API Blocking Credentials on one call, but not another

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-verifiable-credentials

While expanding our WPF Apps emailing functions to include larger attachments, we went from using  the MS GRAPH API endpoint me/sendMail to send emails:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail
```

to using the me/messages endpoint to create a draft so that we could create an upload session to that draft so that we could upload larger attachments (pdf reports)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
```

We are acquiring tokens via MSAL for both. However, when using the second method, we receive the following response:

```
"ErrorAccessDenied"
"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
```

Our expectation was that those two endpoints wouldn't have different credentialing requirements. Our organization's AzureAD accounts are federated delegate, so the only flow we can use is interactive Authorization Code -- so we are calling into MSAL to get the AzureAD token for both endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint for creating a draft message

```
POST /me/messages
```

requires `Mail.ReadWrite` permission. While endpoints for sending mail

```
POST /me/messages/{id}/send
POST /me/sendMail
```

require `Mail.Send`.

Adding `Mail.ReadWrite` permission should resolve the error.